# Using IF Else with IF Statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm using JS to calculate some inputs on a form. I'm using a few IF statements based on the type of user logged in and also the value they have inputted into a field.

To summarise, the formula is structured as follows:

IF logged-in user is administrator or contributor, run formula 1.
Otherwise, if user is subscriber run formula 2.

I wish to add a third rule now, such as, if logged in user is 'customer', run rate 3.

The challenge I'm facing is knowing which IF statement to accommodate the new variation and where it should be placed, I assume, after the first formula?

Here's what I have so far:

```
(function(){
 if(fieldname152=='administrator','contributor') return IF((fieldname130<=1000),(fieldname130)*50.40/1000,IF(fieldname130<=10000,(fieldname130)*50.40/1000,IF(fieldname130<=50000,(fieldname130)*50.90/1000,IF(fieldname130<=500000,(fieldname130)*50.45/1000))));
 else if(fieldname152=='subscriber') return IF((fieldname130<=1000),(fieldname130)*49.40/1000,IF(fieldname130<=10000,(fieldname130)*49.40/1000,IF(fieldname130<=50000,(fieldname130)*48.90/1000,IF(fieldname130<=500000,(fieldname130)*48.45/1000))));
 })()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

S

Comment: That's not very readable, can you neaten up the code a bit?

Comment: Sorry, I've anwered the question myself, it needs to be as follows:

(function(){
if( IN(fieldname152,['administrator','contributor']) )
{
/** The code for the administrators and contributors **/
}

if( fieldname152 == 'role_a' )
{
/** The code for the role_a **/
}


if( fieldname152 == 'role_b' )
{
/** The code for the role_b **/
}
})()

Comment: This article might help you understand `if...else` better: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be much better splitting this code up as follows

```
function calculateValue(userType, value)
{
  var multiplier = 0;
    switch(userType)
  {
    case "administrator":
    case "contributor":
        if (value > 5000000)
      {
        multiplier = 50.45;
      } else if (value > 50000)
      {
        multiplier = 50.9
      } else if (value > 1000)
      {
        multiplier = 50.4
      }
        break;
    case "user":
      // Put your value calculations here
      break;
    default:
      // This is for users other than admin, contrib or user
      if (value > 5000000)
      {
        multiplier = 48.45;
      } else if (value > 50000)
      {
        multiplier = 48.9;
      } else if (value > 1000)
      {
        multiplier = 49.4;
      }
  } // end case
  return value * (multiplier / 1000);

}
```

Then you can call it as follows:

```
var fieldname152 = 'administrator';
var fieldname130 = 500;

var result = calculateValue(fieldname152, fieldname130);
```